# Objcopy equivalent command in Windows

Tags: windows, unix

Is there any way to rename the symbols in the library(*.lib file) in Windows?

In unix, I used **objcopy** command as follows,

**objcopy --redefine-syms "Renamed symbol" "library path"**

I am searching for an equivalent command in windows. Thanks in advance.